# Is it possible to skip the next column with CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm working on a CSS Grid-based layout system and I want to generate offset classes. For example, a ".col-offset-1" class would instruct the element to place itself at the start of the second column along from the previous element.

I've been experimenting with grid-column-start and I thought grid-column-start: span 2; would do the trick in a similar way to how grid-column-end works, but it doesn't. The element still starts on the column defined by its implicit placement and then spans 2 columns instead.

The tricky bit here is I want this to be dynamic, so I can't use specific grid line references to place things manually. I'm looking for a solution that will take whatever implicit column-start placement an element was due to have and move it along by 'X' columns.

See image for reference:
[image: The intended result]

I'm looking for a rule that I could apply to one class to use on both the blue elements and achieve this layout where both skip the column they were due to start on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not possible but you can simulate it if you play with width:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.container > div {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
}
.container > div.offset {
  grid-column:span 2; /* take 2 columns */
  width: calc((100% - 10px)/2); /* take the width of one column */
  margin-left: auto; /* get placed at the second column */
  
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="offset"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="offset"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Temani - damn, I was afraid that might be the case. Thanks for the work around though. I'll see if I can work with that.

Comment: It would be posible to achieve this is subgrid was working in any browser, adding an intermediate div. Right now, it is only posible in Firefox, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to get this, using 2 levels of grid children.

However, it uses subgrid, that is fully suported in Firefox and Safari.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.container > div {
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 2px gray;
}

.container > div > div  {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
}

.offset {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}

.offset > div {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><div>ONE</div></div>
  <div><div>TWO</div></div>
  <div class="offset"><div>XXX</div></div>
  <div><div>3</div></div>
  <div class="offset"><div>Y</div></div>
  <div><div>4</div></div>
  <div><div>xxx</div></div>
  <div><div>xxx</div></div>
  <div><div>xxx</div></div>
  <div><div>xxx</div></div>
  <div><div>xxx</div></div>
  <div><div>xxx</div></div>
  <div><div>xxx</div></div>
  <div><div>xxx</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting! Not usable for me until there's solid browser support as I'll be using this system in production but I've tested the above in Safari and Firefox and yes, that's exactly the behaviour I was after! Good to know it's on its way. Just need to wait for Chromium to get their act together :D

Comment: The bad news is that the Chromium team has been working on this for several years...